# File not found exception when trying to get the ftl template

Tags: java, freemarker, filenotfoundexception

I wrote a java program in which I have to render a ftl and get the output in String variable. 
Please find my code below:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
try 
{
       Template template = cfg.getTemplate("src/response.get.html.ftl");
       model.put("content",contextModel);
       template.process(model, stringWriter);
       System.out.println(stringWriter);

}
```

But am getting file not found exception in `Template template = cfg.getTemplate("src/response.get.html.ftl");`

I have placed my response file in ***src*** and my java file in package ***com.test.webscripts***. According to http://viralpatel.net/blogs/freemaker-template-hello-world-tutorial/  its fine. But am unable to figure out why am I getting the exception. Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `src` is not accessible on runtime, as it's only there for the compiler and the other build tools. After the build was done, the application should only depend on the output of the build (the "binary"), even when in the IDE the `src` is still there (unlike when you deploy the application).

Also, you haven't shown what `TemplateLoader` are you using. You should probably do something like this:

```
cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(SomeClassInMyApp.class, "/");
```

and then:

```
cfg.getTemplate("response.get.html.ftl");
```

It's a safer practice to create a subdirectory, let's say `com/mycompany/myapp/templates`, and put the templates there. In that case you need this:

```
cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(SomeClassInMyApp.class, "/com/mycompany/myapp/templates");
```

Note that then `cfg.getTemplate("response.get.html.ftl"` remains unchanged, as there you specify the path relatively to the template directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your PATH environment variable, Is it contains the path of your workspace and your project path? if not that may cause to that error.

Another easy way to solve your error is to change the path in the following line:

> Template template = cfg.getTemplate("src/response.get.html.ftl");

Instead of the **'src/response.get.html.ftl'** insert the full path from the root directory to your file. i.e: **'c://workspac/username/com/companyname/projectName/src/response.get.html.ftl'**

Note: If you are working with windows make sure your file has no [hidden extension](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/865219).

Comment: @roremy : Thanks for the quick reply... I need to build the jar and use it. So if I hard code the path, it won't work if somebody else use this jar.

Comment: In that situation you can do 1 of 2 things: Add the project path to the PATH environment variable or insert the file to a generic and public directory that any other members of your organization can have access to it. For your local check (to make sure you can use the file on your own computer) you can use the full hardcoded path, it is a small step to solve that error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the method getResource(), for example, in this case:

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Menu.class.getResource("/resource/profut_1.PNG")));
```